# Swift-like "guard-let" in Scala

Tags: scala, if-statement

In Swift, one can do something like:

```swift
guard let x = z else {return}  // z is "String?"
```

In this simple case, if `z` (an optional) is empty, the function will exit.

I really like this structure and recently started developing in Scala, and I was wondering if there's an equivalent in Scala.

What I found is this:

```scala
val x = if (z.isEmpty) return else z.get  // z is "Option[String]"
```

It works - but I still wonder if there's a more "Scala-ish" way of doing it.

**EDIT:** the use case is that a configuration argument is allowed to be `null` in the app, but this specific function has nothing to do in that case. I'm looking for the correct way to avoid calling code that will not work.

Comment: Your scala code is invalid, you cannot have a `return` outside of a method definition. What should the type of `x` be? If `z = Some("string")`, then `x` would be a `String`. But if `z` is `None`, then what should `x` be?

Comment: @Marth being in context of a function is assumed, and I mentioned that `z` is `Option[String]` - which means `x` is expected to be a `String`. If `z` is `None`, there is no `x` because the function will exit. That's the point of Swift's guard-let and what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: What you are trying to do is totally defeating `Option` and should be considered as a code-smell. Do not try to "extract" value from `Option`, but work with `Option`

Comment: @cchantep can you please elaborate, even as an answer? I'm new to Scala, and this is exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for.

Comment: In general, for things like `Option` (and `Either`/`Try`/`Future`/`IO`: monads (which for this purpose roughly means "have `flatMap` and `map`) which are wrapping at most one value), it's generally a good idea to stay in monad land (where whatever semantics the monad imposes remain in force) until you have no choice but to leave (what can I say, it's our happy place).

Answer (score 5):

Scala is functional so using `return` to break out early is almost always a bad idea (partly because `return` doesn't work the way it might appear).

In this case there are a couple of choices.

Using `map` allows the value inside an `Option` to be processed if it is there:

```
val xOpt = z.map { x =>
      // process x
    }
```

`xOpt` is a new `Option` that contains the results of the processing, or `None` if `z` was already `None`.

The alternative is to use a default value if `z` is `None` and then use that.

```
val x = z.getOrElse(defaultX)
// process x
```

In this case `x` is a bare value not an `Option`.

Answer (score 3):

Admittedly I'm not familiar with Swift, but since you're not returning a value, this is presumably in a function being called for side-effect.

In Scala, the natural equivalent for "perform this side-effect if and only if this `Option` is non-empty is `foreach`:

```scala
z.foreach { x =>
  // code that uses x
}
```

There is syntactic sugar around this, the above is equivalent to

```scala
for (
  x <- z
) {  // the absence of yield is significant here
  // code that uses x
}
```

If `z` is empty, the `foreach` does nothing, so the "code that uses `x` would be everything in the function after the guard-let.

It might be that there's an implicit `null` being returned in the early exit case (it's hard to think of another value that would make sense) if this is a function being called for value.  In that case, the natural equivalent would be `map`:

```scala
z.map { x =>
  // code that computes a value from x
} // passes through None if z is empty
```

The `for` sugar would be

```scala
for (
  x <- z
) yield {
  // code that uses x
}
```

As above, "code that uses `x`" means everything after the guard-let.

If you happened to have two nullable arguments like

```swift
guard let x = z else { return }
guard let w = y else { return }
```

You could nest these or have multiple `<-`'s in your `for` expression:

```scala
for {
  x <- z
  w <- y
} yield {
  // code that uses x and w
}
```

Alternatively (and my personal preference), you can use `zip`:

```scala
z.zip(y).foreach {
  case (x, w) =>
    // code that uses x and w
}

// or in the called-for-value case

z.zip(y).map {
  case (x, w) =>
    // code that uses x and w
}.headOption  // zip creates an Iterable, so bring it back to Option
```

Comment: Is it strange that I find the non-sugar syntax more readable?

Comment: @noamtm not really, `for` was created to be more familiar to imperative developers. If you prefer explicit `map` and `flatMap` calls that is great, especially if you latter go more functional like using `IO`

Comment: For `foreach`, I think being explicit that there's a side-effect makes it strictly better than `for` without `yield` (it's easy in review to miss the absence of `yield`).  As for `for` with `yield` (which desugars to `map`/`flatMap`), I personally prefer explicit `map`/`flatMap`, but I may well be in the minority there.

Answer (score 1):

[For comprehensions](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-multiple-options-for-loop-comprehension/) are similar:

```scala
def f(z: Option[String]) = for {
  x <- z  // x is String
  result = x + " okay"
} yield result
```

This is useful when you have *several* short-circuiting operations, but the downside (compared to Swift) is you can't use other control structures such as `if` without some difficulty.

However, `for` in Scala can be used for more than just `Option`, e.g. to process lists:

```scala
def products(xs: Vector[Int], ys: Vector[Int]) = for {
  x <- xs
  y <- ys
} yield x * y  // Result is a Vector of each x multiplied by each y
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that [`Option`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) is a *monad*. Being a *monad* means that it supports [`map`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#map%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):Option%5BB%5D) and [`flatMap`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#flatMap%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EOption%5BB%5D):Option%5BB%5D) and also many other collection operations like [`foreach`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#foreach%5BU%5D(f:A=%3EU):Unit). Being a monad, and specifically supporting `map`, `flatMap`, and `foreach` also means that `Option` can be used as a generator in a [*`for`-comprehension*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops).

The best way of thinking about `Option` is as a *collection* that can hold either 0 or 1 values. (In fact, `Option` *does* inherit from [`IterableOnce`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableOnce.html), and it implements several of the methods of [`Iterable`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html), so you can not just *think* of `Option` as a collection, it simply *is* a collection.) A lot of the knowledge you have about collections transfers *directly* to `Option`, and `Option` supports the most important of the standard Scala collections operations, including the afore-mentioned monad operations.

So, what happens if you iterate over an empty collection? Well, nothing! What happens if you `map` over an empty collection? Well, you get back an empty collection!

So, the *correct* way of working of `Option`s is actually *not* to try and get the value out of it, but instead to treat the `Option` as a collection.

So, instead of trying to get `x` out of the `Option` and then manipulating `x`, you can manipulate the value *inside* of the `Option`.

E.g. if you want to print it:

```scala
z.foreach(println)

// or

for (x <- z) println(x)
```

Iterating over an empty collection doesn't do anything, so this will either do nothing (if the `Option` is empty) or will print the value.

If you want to downcase it:

```scala
val x = z.map(_.toLowerCase())

// or

val x = for (x <- z) yield x.toLowerCase()
```

Note that in my case, `x` is an `Option[String]` (i.e. either a `Some[String]` or `None`) whereas in your case, `x` is a `String`, i.e. in my case, we are staying in the land of `Option`s and don't leave.

Only at the very boundary of your system should you try and extract the value out of the `Option`, and the best way to do that is the method [`getOrElse`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#getOrElse%5BB%3E:A%5D(default:=%3EB):B), which does exactly what it sounds like: it gets the value out of the option if there is one, otherwise it returns the default value that you supplied.